# How to 'free' a TCP port?

Tags: linux, tcp, socket

I have some code that listens to a specific TCP port. However, when I stop this code and restart it quickly afterwards, I see the error

```
ERROR: could not bind to socket on 0.0.0.0:7700
```

If I wait a minute or so, suddenly this port is 'free' and the code runs again.

My question: Is there a way to force this particular port 'free'? To be able to start my code right away, without waiting a minute or so?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `SO_REUSEADDR`

```c
int optval = 1;
/* create socket using socket */
setsockopt(s1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof optval);
/* bind socket */
```

You get this error because the TCP protocol forces the server to put the socket that you just closed into the status `TIME_WAIT` for the time defined in `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout`. This is to ensure that really every packet which the other peer might have sent after your server closed the socket is still being handled correctly.

Here is a nice description of this problem in the top answer of the thread: [What is the meaning of SO_REUSEADDR (setsockopt option) - Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229860/what-is-the-meaning-of-so-reuseaddr-setsockopt-option-linux).

Comment: Is there a way to end the status `TIME_WAIT` for a socket by using just pure linux commands, without changing some code or so?

Comment: you can change the duration of `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout` via `sysctl` and reduce it to a shorter time if you prefer that